# How to return count of function calls between calls with the same input?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to get the value of when was the last time function was called with the same input. If it's the first time, return -1. For example:

```
System.out.println(newNumber(1)); // returns -1
System.out.println(newNumber(2)); // returns -1
System.out.println(newNumber(3)); // returns -1
System.out.println(newNumber(1)); // returns 2
System.out.println(newNumber(2)); // returns 2
System.out.println(newNumber(1)); // returns 1
System.out.println(newNumber(4)); // returns -1
System.out.println(newNumber(1)); // returns 1
```

Having really hard time finding the right way to start doing this. I'm pretty new to hash maps, and I think that's what you have to use?

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: I'm not seeing the pattern in the numbers.  If I call with `1`, three times in a row, what would I expect the output to be?  Can you pseudo-code what the return should be?  (Which is a simple way to start working out how to write the code in general.)

Comment: I don't understand why the second call with an argument of `1` call returns a `2` and the subsequent calls return a `1`.

Comment: Ooohhhh..  I think you're looking for 'return the number of invocations since the last time the same argument was given, or `-1` if that argument has not been given before'?

Comment: Calling with 1 three times a row returns 0 every time, since there are no "gaps". Return is basically the amount of function calls with different numbers between the same numbers. I hope this clears up, I'm not native english speaker and explaining this is pushing my limits in language skills too, lol!

Comment: "return the number of invocations since the last time the same argument was given, or -1 if that argument has not been given before". Exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood the question correctly as:
'Return the number of invocations of the method since the last time the current argument was given, or `-1` if it has never been given before', then you could do this with any `Collection` which maintains insertion order.

For example:

```
private final List<Integer> invocations = new ArrayList<>();

public int newNumber(final int i) {
    if (!this.invocations.contains(i)) {

        // Not seen before, so add to the List, and return -1.
        this.invocations.add(i);
        return -1;
    }

    // size - 1 for 0 indexed list.
    // - last index of it since that was the last time it was called.
    final int lastInvocation
            = this.invocations.size() - 1 - this.invocations.lastIndexOf(i);

    // Remove all prior occurrences of it in the List.
    // Not strictly necessary, but stops the List just growing all the time.
    this.invocations.removeIf(value -> value.equals(i));

    // Add the element as the latest invocation (head of the List)
    this.invocations.add(i);
    return lastInvocation;
}
```

---

Note, thread safety *very much* not considered here.

Comment: No problem.  I'm sure there's _some_ way to do it with a `Set` (which already removes duplicates) but all the ones I could see will leave the _first_ occurrence there rather than remove the old and add the new one to the end.  If this works for you feel free to accept the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

You can store the number of times a number appears in a map from the number to the number of times it appears. Note that this map will have to be a data member to retain the values beyond a single function call.

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
public int newNumber(int i) {
    Integer result = map.computeIfPresent(i, (k, v) -> v + 1);
    if (result == null) {
        map.put(i, 1);
        return -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think this will always return `-1`.  `computeIfPresent` _would_ update if a value was in the `Map`, but none is ever `put` in there.

Comment: @BeUndead arg, true 'dat. Forgot to actually `put` a value there if it's missing, thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.

Comment: No problem.  I was halfway through typing a basically identical answer when the 'new answer' alert popped up.  Upvoted now :).

Comment: This returns the amount of times a function has been called with the given input, but how do I get the info when the function was called last time with the same input? Damn it is hard to explain this, but the main post has return values on comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this works as required.

```
    static Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); 

    public static int newNumber(int n) {
        // store the call count at the null key
        int calls = map.compute(null, (k,v)-> v == null ? 0 : v + 1);

        // initialize the argument entry first time encountered
        map.computeIfAbsent(n, v->calls);

        int c = calls - map.get(n) - 1;
        map.put(n, calls);
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this works too! Thanks. Always nice to see different ways to solve problems.